# How iterate through char *str in C++?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *str;
    gets(str);
    int size = strlen(*(&str));
    //How to iterate through this str which is acting like a string here
    return 0;
}
```

//I'm trying to print each char in a new line.

Comment: Find a good book and a good teacher -> your code is full of problems (it's not your fault, it's because of a bad book/tutorial/school/teacher).

Comment: You should first think about how to properly store the characters entered

Comment: The character pointer `str` does not point to any `char` object and is uninitialized. Use `std::string` instead and a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: use `std::string`, `char *` is not recommended by `g++` compiler

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring all the other problems, such as using an uninitialized pointer, using `gets` (it's so bad it's been *removed* from C and C++), including `bits/stdc++.h`, not using `std::string` and `std::getline`...

Using your `size` variable, you can use loop like this:

```
for(int index = 0 ; index < size ; ++index) {
    std::cout << "character at index " << index << " is '" << str[index] << "'\n";
}
```

But note that your code will crash at `gets` and never get to this loop. Please find better learning material to get started with C++!

---

PS. To get your code to not crash, change `char *str;` to `char str[10000];`... Then that program should run and you are unlikely to *accidentally* cause a buffer overflow. Still, I repeat, get better learning material!

Answer (score 1):

The character pointer `str` doesn't point to any `char` object and has not been **initialized**.

**Second**, the function [`gets`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) has been deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++14.

A better way would be to use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead as shown below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    //take input from user
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    //print out the size of the input string 
    std::cout << str.size() << std::endl;

    //iterate through the input string 
    for(char& element: str)
    {
        std::cout<<element<<std::endl;
    }
}
```